# Calling a function from another function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

I am trying to work out a function in javascript that iterates over about 10 functions.

I have a function that creates service to call a json url into my functions. This communicates with a main function below which calls the service function with options to the corresponding url to use as the data to start the json request. Please see below;

```
var landp = {
getCountryCode : function(){
    console.info('landp.GetCountryCode');
    return window.location.pathname.match(/\/([a-zA-Z]{2})/)[1].toLowerCase();
},
Service : {
    getBaseUrl : function(){
        console.info('landp.Service.GetBaseUrl');
        return sprintf("/%s/service", landp.getCountryCode())
    },
    callService : function(method, options){
        console.info('landp.Service.CallService');
        var url = sprintf("%s/%s", landp.Service.getBaseUrl(), method);
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : 'GET',
            success : options.success,
            error : options.error
        })
    },
    getCategories : function(options){
        landp.Service.callService('category', options);
    },
    getCategoryId : function(options){
        landp.Service.callService('category/id/13', options);
    },
            getCategoryTopTen : function(options){
        landp.Service.callService('category/name/top-ten', options);
    },
    getSeeMoreItems : function(options){
        landp.Service.callService('see-more', options);
    },
    getPartnerOffers : function(options){
        landp.Service.callService('partner-offers', options);
    }
}
```

}

This works okay as you can see getCategoryTopTen will call a url that holds the json data that I need to use to get the right items such as item.name, item.description etc etc. The code for this is below;

```
landp.Service.getCategoryTopTen({
    success : function(data){
        $('#header').after('<div id="cat-sub-options"></div>');
        $('#cat-sub-options').after('<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides"></ul></div><div id="carousel-button" class="click"></div>');            
        $.each(data[0].items, function(i, item){
        $('.flexslider .slides').append('<li class=""><h5>' + i + '</h5><a href="' + item.url + '"><img src="' + item.imageLargeUrl + '" alt="' + item.name + ' image" /><span>' + item.name + '</span></a></li>');
    });
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log("Error getting categories");
    }
})
```

As you can see the code works above and it pulls the right info into the correct elements etc. Currently there are about 10 categories such as;

getCategoryTopTen
getCategoryHistoryHeritage
getCategoryWheretogo
getCategoryShopping
getCategorySportyPeople

As you can see each one will be assigned to a category url in the json file.

What I am trying to fix is how can I do the above for all the categories for instance where we have: landp.Service.getCategoryTopTen with the code below instead of writing itout on every category can I pass a variable instead to each function other wise I will have to do each of these json calls on every category.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Please, use simple string concatenation with the `+` operator, not this `sprintf` function (which does the same internally, or even worse with regex replace etc). JavaScript is a high-level language :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what the issue is but you may benefit quite a bit from using the [] notation for accessing JavaScript children.  So for instance rather than calling
`landp.Service.getCategoryTopTen()` you could call `landp.Service["getCategoryTopTen"]()` and then this could then pulled out so you have something like:

```
var category="TopTen"
var method="getCategory"+category
land.Service[method](...)
```

And then you could wrap your logic around that to iterate or otherwise automate.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand this method?

Comment: In JavaScript you can access any object member through either dot notation `Object.function` or index style notation `Object["function"]`, because the index style uses a string you can operate on that string like you would any other.  This still returns the same object reference.  Since JS has first class functions, once you get the object reference you simply need to call it by adding the `(args)` invocation.  It may be clearer to start if you split it up into to lines and think of it as:

`var method = Object["method"];  method();`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over an array of the method names and call them with the same callback function each time. Getting the function can be done by using the bracket notation:

```
landp.Service[methodname](function(){…});
```

However, I would strongly recommend not to define extra methods for each category in your system, but just make the category name a parameter to your function:

```
…
getCategoryById: function(id, options){
    landp.Service.callService('category/id/'+id, options);
},
getCategoryByName: function(name, options){
    landp.Service.callService('category/name/'+name, options);
},
…
```

Now, the loop over your array is more convenient:

```
var cats = ["top-ten", "HistoryHeritage", "Wheretogo", "Shopping", "SportyPeople"];
for (var i=0; i<cats.length; i++) {
    var catname = cats[i];
    landp.Service.getCategoryByName(catname, {…});
}
```

Btw, you will need to remove the ids from your elements, as you will create them multiple times - but ids need to be unique.

Comment: See the part that creates the slider from the json is the bit that is making things run slow. So that is why I do not want to keep creating the same function with the above code repeated. I am slightly confused with this approach though?

Comment: Yes, your success function will need some adaption if you query more than one service and show the results at the same time